# Find the Non-integer value from a List<T> using LINQ or Lambda C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a class as :

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string Name{set;get;}
  public string Value {set;get;}
  public int ParentId {set;get;}
}
```

My Class Value property can have values like: "1", "MyValue", "2".... and so on.

I have a Generic List `List<MyClass>` and I have to look into the list using LAMBDA or LINQ to fetch the non numeric value i.e. "My Value". Means that I have to fetch the MyClass instance that is having "My Value" in its Value property.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @sloth, All the items must be unique in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var nonInteger = list.Where(x =>
                            {
                                int ignored;
                                return !int.TryParse(x.Value, out ignored);
                            });
```

Or alternatively, wrap the `TryParse` call in a separate method, maybe even an extension method:

```
public static bool CanParseToInt32(this string value)
{
    int ignored;
    return int.TryParse(value, out ignored);
}
```

Then:

```
var nonInteger = list.Where(x => !x.Value.CanParseToInt32());
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried it but not working for me.

Comment: @SyedFasih: "but not working for me" gives me no information to work with. What went wrong? Did it compile but give the wrong results? Did you get an exception? What input did you provide, what output did you expect, and what was the actual output?

Comment: Sorry for less information, It gave me no value. It has to give the desired item that has the string value.

Comment: @SyedFasih: Do you mean it didn't match any instances? It really should - and that query *will* give you the instances that have `Value` properties which can't be parsed as integers. It would really help if you could edit your question with a short but complete example of what you're looking for - then I can plug in my attempted solution and see if it works.

Comment: I am sorry Jon Skeet, Actually I was making a mistake. I was fetching the values from the wrong collection which was next to the intended collection. Your solution is perfect and working for me. Again I am sorry for that. Thanks dear.